# embedify.me Implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed, share, oembed

I'm trying to implement the embedify.me service using jquery, which embeds the data at the link from a url when we share the copy it into the textbox(Very similar to how facebook implements link sharing)

Although the instructions given here, seem pretty simple, me lacking javascript experience means I'm missing some major step, such that the javascript itself is not loading at all.

I have placed all the files in the correct locations.

Instructions

http://www.embedify.me/Home/Documentation#jq

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<link href="/Content/EmbeddedReprUrl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/swfobject.js"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/EmbeddedReprUrl.Config-1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript">      </script> 
     <script src="Scripts/jquery.transform.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
     <script src="Scripts/EmbeddedReprUrl-1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
       <script src="Scripts/EmbeddedRepresentationXsl-1.0.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
  <script src="Scripts/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
    <body>
     <textarea rows="2" cols="50" id="txt" class="embeddor">Enter a URL here       </textarea> 
<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">
          var embeddedReprUrl = new EmbeddedReprUrl(); 
        var postHtml = embeddedReprUrl.GetFullContent($("txt")); 
        alert(postHtml); 
</script>

</body>


     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in EmbeddedReprUrl-1.0.0.js file find this code block : -

```
        if (jQuery.browser.opera) {
            $(selector).bind('input', function (e) {
                var tempEditedElement = $(this); //this is needed for opera, it is forgetting $(this) after timeout
                setTimeout(function () {
                    func(tempEditedElement);
                }, 100);
            });
        } else {
            $(selector).keyup(function (event) {
                var embeddingTriggeringKeyCodes = new Array(8, 13, 32, 45, 46, 86, 88);
                if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, embeddingTriggeringKeyCodes) > -1) {
                    func($(this));
                }
            });
            $(selector).bind('cut paste delete drop', function (e) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    func($(this));
                }, 100);
            });
        }
```

and Replace it with : -

```
$(selector).keyup(function (event) {
                var embeddingTriggeringKeyCodes = new Array(8, 13, 32, 45, 46, 86, 88);
                if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, embeddingTriggeringKeyCodes) > -1) {
                    func($(this));
                }
            });
            $(selector).bind('cut paste delete drop', function (e) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    func($(this));
                }, 100);
            });
```